# Flutter Doctor config

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I used Visual Studio Code for flutter development - still learning - and when I wrote the command "flutter doctor" in the terminal or the cmd I get this all the time:

[image: example-1]
[image: example-2]

Comment: please check your environment variables

Comment: I got the flutter, dart, and android SDKs added and the problem is not fixed

Comment: use android studio to set up flutter, then use vs code as ide. Android studio does all of these things for you.

Comment: I tried but android studio stopped recognizing it.
and it's heavy on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, it took me a while to find a fix. It turns out one may need to explicitly set the SDK directory and/or android studio directory:

`flutter config --android-sdk  q:\tools\android\SDK`

`flutter config --android-studio-dir q:\tools\android`

The symptom (command-line utils not installed) was just because flutter didn't have a place to look. No idea why that wasn't set when I installed Flutter itself, but ... that's what it turned out to be.